# How to debug Notifications on iOS With Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the tutorial to setup Notifications on iOS and I have checked that in the `application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken token: NSData)` function that a FCM token was available `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()`.

From the Firebase Console I tried to send a notification (status is `Completed`) but no notification was received on my iOS Device.

In order to check the 'Apple side', I have uploaded y push notification certificates into another Push Notification Service Provided and it works.

So I would like to know how can I debug my application?

Comment: What target are you using in the console? If you are using a device token then I'd double check that you are using the correct token. Sometimes during registration you can receive multiple tokens and thus the first one you retrieve may no longer be valid. Be sure to add an observer so you will be notified of any changes in the token and call instanceID().token() there. see https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/FCM/AppDelegate.m#L50

Comment: Thanks, but the provided code seems to be necessary for Firebase Messaging and I would like to use only Apple Push Notifications. So, is it mandatory to connect to Firebase Messaging in order to receive APNS Notifications?

Comment: No, you can receive APNs messages without using Firebase, however you cannot receive FCM messages without using Firebase. So if you are sending messages from the Firebase console, you need to implement Firebase on the client to receive those messages.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try to implement FCM messaging.

Comment: Note that there's a [blog on debugging FCM](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html). Some of the details there would be relevant.